# PayPal-node-SDK `Subscription start date should be greater than current date` always occurs after 12 am

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I live in Hong Kong and I always get this sandbox paypal transaction error after midnight from `paypal.billingAgreement.execute()`. The error goes away in the afternoon, probably because the place where paypal server is located finally gets past the midnight.

```
{    name: 'SUBSCRIPTION_UNMAPPED_ERROR',
     message: 'Subscription start date should be greater than current date',
     information_link: 'https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements#errors',
     debug_id: 'd2e618eef4162',
     httpStatusCode: 400
 },
```

I know this is a timezone problem with the sandbox environment but I can't figure out how to solve it.

My billing agreement is created as per the example in [PayPal-node-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/master/samples/subscription/billing_agreements/create.js)

```
process.env.TZ = 'utc';
var isoDate = new Date();
isoDate.setSeconds(isoDate.getSeconds() + 4);
isoDate.toISOString().slice(0, 19) + 'Z';

var billingAgreementAttributes = {
    "start_date": isoDate,
    /..../
}
```

I have set the `TZ` environment variable in nodes to `utc`;

The time zone setting of the sandbox account I use to log in and subscribe:

[image]

I've also tried different zones like `Eastern Time` but it has no effects.

Comment: You may explicitly set it to your country's timezone like that: `process.env.TZ = 'Hongkong';` Also would you please try to set`start_date` manually(hardcoded) to something like this `"start_date": "2018-02-19T00:37:04Z"`. I don't believe that `isoDate` trick works..

Comment: @gokcand okay, I'll try that. Do you think this `start_date` problem only occurs in the sandbox mode. Will it still happen when the app goes live?

Comment: I think that sandbox mode probably mimics the prod environment completely. So it may happen in live mode too. Btw, have you tried my solution?

Comment: @gokcand Changing the environment timezone variable doesn't work. I have to set the start date a month ahead `let startDate = moment().add(1,'month').toISOString().slice(0, 19) + 'Z'` and use `setup_fee` in `merchant_preferences` if I want to charge the user right after the subscription is created. I couldn't find any other way.

Comment: What does this line: `isoDate.toISOString().slice(0, 19) + 'Z';` do? Maybe it should be `isoDate = isoDate.toISOString().....`

Answer (score 2):

As per PayPal Docs, StartDate should be UTC, looks 
Setting Process Time Zone

```
 process.env.TZ = 'utc';
```

has no effect in your code(some time it might be cashed), can you check the date variable value is in UTC?

I would suggest to change

```
var isoDate = new Date();
```

to

```
var isoDate = new Date().toISOString();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm not able to try your suggestion now because it's not midnight in Hong Kong when the problem occurs, But my code already uses `toISOString()` in `var isoDate = new Date();
isoDate.setSeconds(isoDate.getSeconds() + 4);
isoDate.toISOString().slice(0, 19) + 'Z';`
`